# Loading bundled AMD modules with SystemJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, systemjs, es6-module-loader, es6-modules

I have a couple of AMD modules compiled using TypeScript's `--outFile` option into a single file:

```
define("partA", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    function partAFunc() {
        console.log('partAFunc');
        return 'partAFunc';
    }
    exports.partAFunc = partAFunc;
});
define("partB", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    exports.partB = 42;
});
define("partC", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    ...
});
```

Now I want to load only the `partA` module and call its `partAfunc()` so I can do the following in Node.js:

```
SystemJS.config({
  map: {
    'main': 'my-bundle.js',
  },
});

SystemJS.import('main').then((m) => {
  SystemJS.import('partA').then((m) => {
    m.partAFunc();
  });
});
```

The first import `SystemJS.import('main')` just registers all the modules and then `SystemJS.import('partA')` works because module `partA` is already registered (or at least I guess that's what it does).

However, why I can't just use `SystemJS.import('partA')` and set the bundle as a dependency:

```
SystemJS.config({
  meta: {
    'partA': {
      deps: [ 'my-bundle.js' ],
    }
  }
});

SystemJS.import('partA').then((m) => {
  m.partAFunc();
});
```

The `meta` is completely ignored. The doc at https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#meta says:

> Dependencies to load before this module. Goes through regular paths and map normalization. Only supported for the cjs, amd and global formats.

It looks like SystemJS first checks whether the file `partA` exists (which obviously doesn't) and throws an error (I tested it with an existing file and the `meta` config worked):

```
(node:60981) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/.../partA'
  Instantiating /Users/.../partA
  Loading partA
```

I'd expect that also the following should work when the first variant works with two nested `SystemJS.import` calls.

```
SystemJS.config({
  map: {
    'partA': 'my-bundle.js',
  },
});

SystemJS.import('partA').then((m) => {
  // m.partAFunc();
  console.log(m)
});
```

This prints an empty object. It looks like when there're more than one module in a single file it just registers them and doesn't load any of them?

I read all the documents in https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/tree/master/docs but I think I'm still lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is use the [`bundles`](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#bundles) setting and set your bundle like this:

```
    bundles: {
      'my-bundle.js': ['partA', 'partB', 'partC'],
    },
```

Roughly, this tells SystemJS "when you look for module `partA`, fetch and execute the module named `my-bundle.js` and you'll find `partA` there."

---

Your approach using `meta` cannot work. Your `meta` setting does not say "don't try to fetch a module named partA and *instead* fetch `my-bundle.js`" it says "when you process `partA`, *in addition to the dependencies it already has*, add `my-bundle.js` to the list of dependencies." SystemJS will still fetch `partA`. There's no reason for it to wait until it has executed `my-bundle.js` before it tries to fetch it, so it launches the fetch immediately and it fails.

Comment: I thought the `bundles` option works only with bundles created with SystemJS Builder which means I need to use System module format. I'm using AMD format. I think I understand now what the `deps` does. It loads the modules in order so both need to exist but then they're executed with `deps` first.

Comment: You can use `bundle` with AMD modules. I've done it. No SystemJS builder involved. The documentation is misleading. What it says about the builder and using `System.register` is for the purpose of illustration (that's *one* way to do it). It is not *prescriptive*.

Comment: That's interesting, I just tested it and it really works with AMD modules too.